# Clip cut but isn't removing the space

Tags: css, space, clip

Well it was hard to find a title so i will explain myselft properly here.

[image]

So i cut this block left bottom corner with the css clip but this property only "hidde" my blue space and i want to cut and remove the space created by this corner.

So my question is how to do this...?
here is my html/css :

```css
#japon
{
    width: 800px;
    height: 730px;
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    right:0px;
    border: 3px solid black;
    clip:rect(0px,806px,830px,-780px);
}

#blockjapon
{
    width: 800px;
    height: 730px;
    background-color:#65d5fd;
    transform: rotate(345deg);
    border:3px solid black;
}
```

```html
    <section id="japon">
        
        <div id="blockjapon"></div>
        
    </section>
```

Comment: Is your section#japon a direct child of body? Or is it wrapped around something else?

Comment: it's a direct child of body

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This workaround hides the body horizontal overflow, but keep in mind that will work only if `#japon` sets `right:0px;`

```css
body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
#japon
{
    width: 800px;
    height: 730px;
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    right:0px;
    border: 3px solid black;
    clip:rect(0px,806px,830px,-780px);
}

#blockjapon
{
    width: 800px;
    height: 730px;
    background-color:#65d5fd;
    transform: rotate(345deg);
    border:3px solid black;
}
```

```html
<section id="japon">
        
        <div id="blockjapon"></div>
        
    </section>
```

Answer (score -1):

If you just add `overflow: hidden` to the outer div, it seems to solve it.

```css
#japon
{
    width: 800px;
    height: 730px;
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    overflow:hidden; /* <--- */
    right:0px;
    border: 3px solid black;
    clip:rect(0px,806px,830px,-780px);
}

#blockjapon
{
    width: 800px;
    height: 730px;
    background-color:#65d5fd;
    transform: rotate(345deg);
    border:3px solid black;
}
```

```html
    <section id="japon">
        
        <div id="blockjapon"></div>
        
    </section>
```

Comment: this solution hides the left side too.

Comment: yeah, well, I am not really familiar with this new CSS, it looked good. The "clip" property has no effect for me tho, not sure what it was meant to do.

Comment: yeah but i don't want the other sides cut out :/ thanks anyway